# Weighted multidim fit using Math.net numerics

Tags: math.net

I am using the `Fit.LinearMultiDim` method to fit a 4-parameter function to a multidimensional dataset (2-dim). More specific: I fit the function

(x1,x2) => p1 + p2*x1 + p3*x1*x1 + p4*x2

```
FitParameters = Fit.LinearMultiDim(xy, z,
    d => 1.0,         // p0*1.0
    d => d[0],        // p1*x1
    d => d[0] * d[0], // p2*x1^2
    d => d[1]);       // p3*x2
```

Now I have the problem that I also want to use weights for the xy datapoints. I know I can use `Fit.MultiDimWeighted`, but in this case I only have a linear plane and can not implement the square dependency used for parameter 2.

Do you have any idea how I can combine the two?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the Math.Net code I found a solution to combine both a multidim fit together with weighted datapoints. Hope this helps somebody if he encounters the same question.

In the source code I run:

```
FitParametersModel1 = MyFitFunctionModel1(xy, z, w,
    d => 1.0,           // p0*1.0
    d => d[0],          // p1*x1
    d => d[0] * d[0],   // p2*x1^2
    d => d[1]);         // p3*x2
```

And the function `MyFitFunctionModel1` looks like this:

```
public double[] MyFitFunctionModel1(double[][] x, double[] y, double[] w, params Func<double[], double>[] functions)
{
    var design = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(x.Length, functions.Length, (i, j) => functions[j](x[i]));
    return MathNet.Numerics.LinearRegression.WeightedRegression.Weighted(design, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<double>.Build.Dense(y), MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix<double>.Build.Diagonal(w)).ToArray();
}
```